# What is the equivalent DateAndTime.DateAdd in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I have an old code written in VB.Net and I am trying to convert it into c#. I am stuck on `DateAndTime.DateAdd` conversion for c#

```
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Now).ToString("MMM")
```

This is my old vb.net code. It is getting the current month and subtracting - one month from it.

How do I achieve this c#?

Comment: Looks like code is trying to get last day of the month.  So code is adding one month and subtracting one day.

Comment: @jdweng just the previous month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DateTime.AddMonths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=net-6.0).

Pay attention:

> Returns a new DateTime

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
var stringDate = date.ToString("MMM");
```